# Consider the map $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[X]\to\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}, f(X)\mapsto(f(2),f(-2))$ Prove that $\ker(\phi)=\langle X^{2}-4\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the map $\phi:\mathbb{Q}[X]\to\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}, f(X)\mapsto(f(2),f(-2))$

Prove that $\ker(\phi)=\langle X^{2}-4\rangle$.

I've already proven that: $\langle X^{2}-4\rangle\subseteq\ker(\phi)$

For the other inclusion, I can't prove it.

Comment: hint: $f(a) = 0$ if and only if $(x-a) | f(x)$.

Comment: To get started, suppose $f(X)\in\ker(\phi)$. Then $\phi(f(X))=(0,0)\implies (f(2),f(-2))=(0,0)$. What can you deduce from here?

Comment: we get that $(X-2)|f(x)$ and $(x-2)|f(x)$ so there is a g, h s.t $f(x)=(x-2)g(x)$ and $f(x)=(x+2)h(x)$ but this only implies that f is in $<X-2>$ and in $<X+2>$ not in $X^{2}-4$

Comment: Close. If $(X-2)$ and $(X+2)$ are factors if $f$, then $f(X)=(X-2)(X+2)g(X)$.

Comment: I GOT IT. It means it belongs to the intersection and $<X^{2}-4>$ is equal to said intersection as it is the lcm

Comment: @Bonnaduck isn't this reasoning also valid?

Comment: Yes, that's correct as well. It's recommended that you submit an answer to your own question and accept your answer.

Comment: Hmm thanks total noob here

Answer (score 3):

This answer was made possible by the comments.

Suppose $f(x) \in \ker(\phi)$.

$f(x) \in \ker(\phi) \Rightarrow \phi (f(x))=0$

$\Rightarrow (f(2),f(-2))=(0,0)$
$\Rightarrow f(2)=0$ and $f(-2)=0$

$\Rightarrow (x-2)\mid f(x)$ and $(x+2)\mid f(x)$
$\Rightarrow f(x)\in \langle x-2\rangle$ and $f(x) \in \langle x+2\rangle$
$\Rightarrow f(x) \in \langle x-2\rangle \cap \langle x+2\rangle$
$\Rightarrow f(x) \in \langle X^{2}-4\rangle$

The last "$\Rightarrow$" comes from the fact that ${\rm lcm}(x-2,x+2)=x^{2}-4$
and $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle = \langle {\rm lcm}(a,b)\rangle$